# Swift, iOS 14: where to find device logs?

Tags: ios, swift, ios14

I am trying to debug my app and I need to log some info. Here is my code:

```
let logger = Logger(subsystem: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!, category: "main")
                logger.log("One")
                logger.notice("Two")
                os_log("Three")
```

But when I press *Cmd-Shift-2* -> *View Device Logs* after that, it doesn't show any logs related to my app. I want to read these messages somewhere - how do I do that?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging/viewing_log_messages Use the `log` command line tool. See https://www.manpagez.com/man/1/log/. Note that you can filter by date and subsystem / category, so you can get the right ones. Also note that logs do not persist forever.

Comment: I provide a couple of examples in https://www.biteinteractive.com/the-joys-of-logging/

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the macOS console.app to see your logs.

**Additional information »** Exploring logging in Swift: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10168/